# Is there a way to identify audio outputs in a unique way?

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, directsound, windows-core-audio

How can I identify each audio output? It can be a monitor. How can we identify its proper audio output?

Comment: Both, I used direct sound but it does not look to have what I need. But I can go for any of the APIs @user17732522

Comment: Core Audio is a macOS / iOS thing (as the tag description makes clear).  Did you mean [WASAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/wasapi)?

Comment: @PaulSanders https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_coreaudio/ This one is used for Windows.

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/device-properties) help you at all?

Comment: Created a new tag, `windows-core-audio`.

Comment: @PaulSanders I'm at the point of reading all the documentation to see if it helps. Maybe there is a flag.

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what you want because of the lack of detail in the question, but you should read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmdeviceapi/nf-mmdeviceapi-immdevice-getid).  There's an example of how to call it (`pEndpoint->GetId`) in the previous link I posted.

Comment: @PaulSanders This is what I use, I'm able to get these properties https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/core-audio-properties, but none of them can identify a screen audio output directly

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by 'identify a screen audio output'. You need to add that information to your question. What, in particular, do you want to use to identify it?

Comment: @PaulSanders I would like to identify the output sound for lets say monitor no.3 if I have 3 monitors.

Comment: Audio endpoints, as Microsoft call them, are not associated with monitors (do you mean screens?) in any way.  They are just, in the case of output devices, things you can send an audio output stream to.  There is nothing special about the speakers built into your monitor (if that is what you're driving at).

Comment: So enlist the help of your user: Display a list of available audio output devices and a 'Test' button which plays a short burst of audio through the selected device.  Then invite him / her to try each device in turn until they find the one they want.  That's what I do (I use Beethoven's Fifth - out of copyright :)

Comment: @PaulSanders, ok I see, yes I want to identify which audio output is directed to which screen. So there is not way to programmatically do this association without playing a sound and letting a user to this association himself.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.